# What is the budget of a typical modern B-movie?

Tags: film-industry

B movies are generally considered to be low budget films without the greatest production values. But where is the line in the sand that divides a B-movie from its richer brethren? (Also, who draws this line? The critics?)

Is [Insidious: Chapter 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insidious%3a_Chapter_2) considered a B-movie? It was apparently made on a budget of USD 5M and has raked in USD 102M.

Comment: In answer to the other question, no, I wouldn't consider Insidious 2 a B-movie. It is really well-crafted and there is no sign of any tongues in cheeks ;)

Answer (score 7):

A B-Movie isn't really a measure of budget, but rather is a genre all of its own.

For example, by your criteria *The Blair Witch Project* would be considered a B-Movie due to its tiny budget and low production values, but this is not the case. At the other end of the spectrum, we could consider *Pacific Rim* to be one of the biggest budgeted B-movies around, so it is worth examining what constitutes a B-movie.

This [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_movie) contains a lot of interesting information, namely that the B-movie has evolved from being the second (or 'bottom') movie in a double-bill into a class of its own - glorified and emulated by seasoned professionals in the industry.

Another great example to consider is *Mars Attacks* which is a supremely well-crafted, big budget movie with its roots firmly in B-movie territory.

At the end of the day, the whole B-movie genre is rather ambiguous, often (as you suggest) at the mercy of critics who like to pigeon-hole films. For the record, most of the movies coming out of the Asylum or SyFy stables are considered B-movies, and it is true that their budgets rarely exceed $1.5M and the production quality is sometimes horrendous.

It seems the whole genre hangs on the whim of critical reception and filmmaker intentions, and probably less to do with investment.

Comment: Thanks. Personally, I don't consider either _Mars Attacks_ or _Pacific Rim_ to be B-movies. They are just parodies of or homages to "old school" B-movies. So is it just a case of labels having changed? Are what were B-movies called something else now? I don't think _arthouse_ or _independent_ (as _Blair Witch_ was) really fit. How would you classify _The Brown Bunny_, _Primer_ and _Alone with Her_ (from the wiki)?

Comment: Brown Bunny - art film
Primer - sci fi
Alone with Her - thriller
But there I go, forcing my own labels onto them... hence the ambiguity :)

Comment: One of my film-class textbooks described part of the distinction in terms of the investment model.  A B-movie production company would in many cases have a contract to produce some number of movies for a certain price, and would have no direct financial interest in how its films performed beyond possible effects on future contracts.  Feature films carry a lot of downside risk but have significant upside potential as well.  In many cases, B movies had neither.  If a contract said a production house would get paid X dollars it would get paid X dollars whether the film was good or garbage.

Answer (score 0):

$5m to $20m is a reasonable guess.
You can do your own budget quite easily using [this guide on planning an indie budget](http://www.moviemaker.com/archives/mm_guide_2014/beginners-guide-budget/).